# Is there any method to send a different message for each device token in a single google server api call?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have a doubt whether we can send different messages to each device in a single API call to Google server, like `payloadperdevice` option in `java_apns`.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't. You either send the same message to multiple Registration IDs (up to 1000) in the same HTTP request, or you send different messages to different devices in different HTTP requests.

BTW, Apple Push Notifications Service doesn't have this feature either. The difference between APNS and GCM is that in APNS you have an open socket that you keep writing messages to without getting a response (unless you send invalid data), while in GCM (at least in the HTTP version), you send a request and receive a response for each message. Therefore, in APNS, it can look like you are sending multiple messages in a single API call, while internally you are actually iterating over the messages to be sent and writing each one separately to the socket.

`java_apns` wraps the APNS API in order to make it look like you can make such a single API call. Similarly, you can write your own API that wraps the GCM API and makes it look like you can send multiple different messages in a single API call. However, your single API call will be split internally to multiple API calls to GCM.